# How to receive and make phone calls?

Tags: android

I was researching this but couldn't find out how to make and recieve calls in a application that is not made by the user. My question is like this question [How to send and receive SMS from android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869961/how-to-send-and-receive-sms-from-android-app) but for phone calls.

Comment: You mean "application that **is** made by the user"? Because your native dialer app is one not made by the user

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to open the dialer from your app you can do it via a simple intent such as `Intent.ACTION_CALL`, this opens up the dialer(rememebr to request the required permissions in the manifest). You can also listen for telephone events by overriding the `PhoneStateListener()`. [This link talks more about this in detail.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-calls-and-use-sms-in-android-apps--cms-28168)